# mmapping a file and indexing into the memory for read/ write

Tags: c, mmap

I'm trying to model a basic CPU by mmapping a 1 MiB file, corresponding to the RAM size. I want to read/write this file. My confusion is that I thought I could just mmap my file, and then index into the memory chunk as if it were an array. I've seen a few examples online that have done as much. For example, given the snippet below:

```
int16_t ramD;
if ( (ramD = open("ramMap.txt", O_RDWR | O_CREAT, 1)) == -1)
{
    errx(EX_OSERR, "RAM could not be initialized");
}
uint16_t* ram = mmap(0, ram_bytes, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, ramD, 0);
```

How would I access specific locations within this mmapped file for reading and writing? I thought it would be as simple as something like `ram[36]` which would give me access to the 36th byte offset from the pointer returned by mmap, but this doesn't seem to be the case. To test I did a `printf("%p\n", (void *) &ram);` to see what address mmap was pointing to which gave me `0x7fffffffde18`, (which, by the way, is nowhere close to my specified mmap parameter 0). Meanwhile, `printf("%p\n", (void *) &ram[36])` returns `0x7ffff7ee1048`.

Is mmap not giving me memory in a linear chunk? What am I missing here?

Comment: You cannot put the array (or anything) at address `0`. The documentation
 on `mmap` says: "If addr is NULL, then the kernel chooses the address at which to create the mapping;". One other issue is that you seem to intend to read bytes over a pointer to `uint16_t` (which is likely 2 bytes here).

Comment: `printf("%p\n", (void *) &ram);` here you are printing the address of the `ram` variable, likely allocated on the stack judging from the printed address. You probably want `printf("%p\n", (void *) ram);`.

Comment: If you store the base address in a `uint16_t *`, then `ram[36]` addresses the bytes at offsets 72 and 73, not byte 36, because the size is in multiples of the size of the unit pointed at.  If it were an array of `int`, it would be annoying to have to write `array_of_int[offset*sizeof(int)]` to get the integer at offset.  C doesn't make you do that; you write `array_of_int[offset]` to get at the integer.  Similar comments apply to `uint16_t *`.

Comment: Are you on macOS, by any chance?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler no, Windows using a cloud-based ubuntu IDE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This

```
printf("%p\n", (void *) &ram);
```

gives you the address of your local variable `ram` on the stack.  You want

```
printf("%p\n", (void *)ram);
```

to get the address of the ram you mmapped.  Also, since you declared `ram` as a `uint16_t`,  `ram[36]` will be the 36th<sup>1</sup> 16-bit word of the memory (bytes 72 and 73).

---

<sup>1</sup><sub>Counting from 0 of course</sub>

Comment: Thanks, this clears up a lot. Still an issue though: I'm getting `0x7ffff7ee1000` from `printf("%p\n", (void*) ram)` , but  when I try to get the address of `ram[36]` via `printf("%p\n", (void*) &ram[36])`, I get `0x7ffff7ee1024`. Still not what I was expecting. This is after changing the type of ram to uint8_t*.

Comment: @DavidMcGee: If the pointer is `uint8_t *`, then a base address `ram = 0x7FFFF7EE1000` means that `&ram[36]` should be `0x7FFFF7EE1024` (since hex 24 == dec 36).